# Can't recover attribute from object within list of object using foreach in twig - symfony

Tags: php, html, symfony, foreach, twig

Here is an example of my object :

```
^ array:1 [▼
0 => App\Entity\Fichefrais {#601 ▼
    -idfichefrais: "a131-202201"
    -date: DateTime @1640995200 {#602 ▶}
    -nbjustificatifs: null
    -montantvalide: null
    -datemodif: null
    -idetat: Proxies\__CG__\App\Entity\Etat {#603 ▶}
    -idvisiteur: Proxies\__CG__\App\Entity\Visiteur {#604 ▶}
    -lignesfraishorsforfait: App\Entity\Listelignesfraishorsforfait {#622 ▼
      +"0": App\Entity\Lignefraishorsforfait {#623 ▼
        -idlignefraishorsforfait: 1
        -libelle: "fournitures tech"
        -date: DateTime @1641254400 {#624 ▶}
        -montant: "7620.45"
        -idfichefrais: App\Entity\Fichefrais {#625 ▶}
      }
      +"1": App\Entity\Lignefraishorsforfait {#629 ▼
        -idlignefraishorsforfait: 2
        -libelle: "location salle"
        -date: DateTime @1641254400 {#630 ▶}
        -montant: "720.00"
        -idfichefrais: App\Entity\Fichefrais {#625 ▶}
      }
    }
    +"ETP": App\Entity\Lignefraisforfait {#605 ▶}
    +"KM": App\Entity\Lignefraisforfait {#610 ▶}
    +"NUI": App\Entity\Lignefraisforfait {#614 ▶}
    +"REP": App\Entity\Lignefraisforfait {#618 ▶}
  }
1 => App\Entity\Fichefrais {#601 ▼
    -idfichefrais: "a131-202112"
    -date: DateTime @1640995200 {#602 ▶}
    -nbjustificatifs: null
    -montantvalide: null
    -datemodif: null
    -idetat: Proxies\__CG__\App\Entity\Etat {#603 ▶}
    -idvisiteur: Proxies\__CG__\App\Entity\Visiteur {#604 ▶}
    -lignesfraishorsforfait: null
    +"ETP": App\Entity\Lignefraisforfait {#605 ▶}
    +"KM": App\Entity\Lignefraisforfait {#610 ▶}
    +"NUI": App\Entity\Lignefraisforfait {#614 ▶}
    +"REP": App\Entity\Lignefraisforfait {#618 ▶}
  }
2 => App\Entity\Fichefrais {#601 ▼
    -idfichefrais: "a131-202112"
    -date: DateTime @1640995200 {#602 ▶}
    -nbjustificatifs: null
    -montantvalide: null
    -datemodif: null
    -idetat: Proxies\__CG__\App\Entity\Etat {#603 ▶}
    -idvisiteur: Proxies\__CG__\App\Entity\Visiteur {#604 ▶}
    -lignesfraishorsforfait: App\Entity\Listelignesfraishorsforfait {#622 ▼
      +"0": App\Entity\Lignefraishorsforfait {#623 ▼
        -idlignefraishorsforfait: 1
        -libelle: "car rent"
        -date: DateTime @1641254400 {#624 ▶}
        -montant: "226.45"
        -idfichefrais: App\Entity\Fichefrais {#625 ▶}
      }
      +"1": App\Entity\Lignefraishorsforfait {#629 ▼
        -idlignefraishorsforfait: 2
        -libelle: "uber"
        -date: DateTime @1641254400 {#630 ▶}
        -montant: "46.00"
        -idfichefrais: App\Entity\Fichefrais {#625 ▶}
      }
      +"2": App\Entity\Lignefraishorsforfait {#629 ▼
        -idlignefraishorsforfait: 3
        -libelle: "food"
        -date: DateTime @1641254400 {#630 ▶}
        -montant: "26.00"
        -idfichefrais: App\Entity\Fichefrais {#625 ▶}
      }
    }
    +"ETP": App\Entity\Lignefraisforfait {#605 ▶}
    +"KM": App\Entity\Lignefraisforfait {#610 ▶}
    +"NUI": App\Entity\Lignefraisforfait {#614 ▶}
    +"REP": App\Entity\Lignefraisforfait {#618 ▶}
   }
]
```

I want to use twig to print each `montant` of each `Lignefraishorsforfait` (n number of `Lignefraishorsforfait` can exist) of each `Listelignesfraishorsforfait` of each `Fichefrais` if `Lignefraishorsforfait` is not null in the `Fichefrais`.

Here what i did so far, but it doesn't work, nothing shows up:

```
 {% for unefichefrais in fichesfrais %}
    {% if unefichefrais.lignesfraishorsforfait is null %}
       {{ 0 }} €
    {% else %}
       {% for unelignefraishorsforfait in unefichefrais.lignesfraishorsforfait %}
          {{ unelignefraishorsforfait.montant }}
       {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
 {% endfor %}
```

edit : just corrected an error in my code, but it doesn't change anything, I still have nothing showing up, but the if condition works because 0 doesn't appear... so it means that there is an attribute.

here are further classes and informations :

Fichefrais class:

```
    <?php


namespace App\Entity;

use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\VirtualProperty;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\SerializedName;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Fichefrais
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="FicheFrais", uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="idFicheFrais", columns={"idFicheFrais"})}, indexes={@ORM\Index(name="idEtat", columns={"idEtat"}), @ORM\Index(name="idVisiteur", columns={"idVisiteur"})})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\FichefraisRepository")
 */
class Fichefrais
{

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="idFicheFrais", type="string", length=12, nullable=false, options={"fixed"=true})
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $idfichefrais;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date", type="date", nullable=false)
     */
    private $date;

    /**
     * @var int|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nbJustificatifs", type="integer", nullable=true, options={"default"="NULL"})
     */
    private $nbjustificatifs = NULL;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="montantValide", type="decimal", precision=10, scale=2, nullable=true, options={"default"="NULL"})
     */
    private $montantvalide = 'NULL';

    /**
     * @var \DateTime|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="dateModif", type="date", nullable=true, options={"default"="NULL"})
     */
    private $datemodif = 'NULL';

    /**
     * @var \Etat
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Etat")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="idEtat", referencedColumnName="idEtat")
     * })
     */
    private $idetat;

    /**
     * @var \Visiteur
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Visiteur")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="idVisiteur", referencedColumnName="idVisiteur")
     * })
     */
    private $idvisiteur;

    /**
     * @var \Listelignesfraishorsforfait
     */
    private $lignesfraishorsforfait;

    public function getlignesfraishorsforfait(): ?Listelignesfraishorsforfait{
        return $this->lignesfraishorsforfait;
    }


    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->idfraisforfait = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /** TO STRING FOR ID */
    public function __toString()
    {
        return (string) $this->getIdfichefrais();
    }

    public function getIdfichefrais(): ?string
    {
        return $this->idfichefrais;
    }

    public function getDate(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->date;
    }

    public function setDate(\DateTimeInterface $date): self
    {
        $this->date = $date;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getNbjustificatifs(): ?int
    {
        return $this->nbjustificatifs;
    }

    public function setNbjustificatifs(?int $nbjustificatifs): self
    {
        $this->nbjustificatifs = $nbjustificatifs;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getMontantvalide(): ?string
    {
        return $this->montantvalide;
    }

    public function setMontantvalide(?string $montantvalide): self
    {
        $this->montantvalide = $montantvalide;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDatemodif(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->datemodif;
    }

    public function setDatemodif(?\DateTimeInterface $datemodif): self
    {
        $this->datemodif = $datemodif;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getIdetat(): ?Etat
    {
        return $this->idetat;
    }

    public function setIdetat(?Etat $idetat): self
    {
        $this->idetat = $idetat;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getIdvisiteur(): ?Visiteur
    {
        return $this->idvisiteur;
    }

    public function setIdvisiteur(?Visiteur $idvisiteur): self
    {
        $this->idvisiteur = $idvisiteur;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Fraisforfait[]
     */
    public function getIdfraisforfait(): Collection
    {
        return $this->idfraisforfait;
    }

    public function addIdfraisforfait(Fraisforfait $idfraisforfait): self
    {
        if (!$this->idfraisforfait->contains($idfraisforfait)) {
            $this->idfraisforfait[] = $idfraisforfait;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeIdfraisforfait(Fraisforfait $idfraisforfait): self
    {
        $this->idfraisforfait->removeElement($idfraisforfait);

        return $this;
    }

    static function convertObjectClass($array, $final_class) {
        return unserialize(sprintf('O:%d:"%s"%s', strlen($final_class), $final_class, strstr(serialize($array), ':')
        ));
    }
```

}

Listelignesfraishorsforfait class:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use JetBrains\PhpStorm\Internal\LanguageLevelTypeAware;
use Traversable;

class Listelignesfraishorsforfait
{
    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    public function addLignefraishorsforfait(Lignefraishorsforfait  $Lignefraishorsforfait)
    {
        $lignefraishorsforfait=$Lignefraishorsforfait->getIdlignefraishorsforfait();
        $this->$lignefraishorsforfait = $Lignefraishorsforfait;
    }

    public function getLignefraishorsforfait(): Lignefraishorsforfait
    {
        return $this->Lignefraishorforfait;
    }

    public function setLignefraishorsforfait(Lignefraishorsforfait $Lignefraishorforfait): void
    {
        $this->Lignefraishorforfait = $Lignefraishorforfait;
    }

    public function getcount()
    {
        $nblignesfraishorsforfait=count((array)$this);
        dump($nblignesfraishorsforfait=$nblignesfraishorsforfait-1);
        return $nblignesfraishorsforfait;
    }

    /*public function getTotal(): int
    {
        foreach($this as $unelignefraisforfait){
            $somme = $unelignefraisforfait->getMontant();
            $montant = $montant + $somme;
        }
        $unelignefraisforfait=$this->convertObjectClass(
            array_merge((array)$this, (array)$montant
            ),'App\Entity\Lignefraishorsforfait');
        dump($unelignefraisforfait);
        return $unelignefraisforfait;
    }*/
}
```

Lignefraishorsforfait class:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Lignefraishorsforfait
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="LigneFraisHorsForfait", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="idFicheFrais", columns={"idFicheFrais"})})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\LignefraishorsforfaitRepository")
 */
class Lignefraishorsforfait
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="idLigneFraisHorsForfait", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
     */
    private $idlignefraishorsforfait;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="libelle", type="string", length=100, nullable=true, options={"default"="NULL"})
     */
    private $libelle = 'NULL';

    /**
     * @var \DateTime|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date", type="date", nullable=true, options={"default"="NULL"})
     */
    private $date = 'NULL';

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="montant", type="decimal", precision=10, scale=2, nullable=true, options={"default"="NULL"})
     */
    private $montant = 'NULL';

    /**
     * @var \Fichefrais
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Fichefrais")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="idFicheFrais", referencedColumnName="idFicheFrais")
     * })
     */
    private $idfichefrais;

    public function getIdlignefraishorsforfait(): ?int
    {
        return $this->idlignefraishorsforfait;
    }

    public function getLibelle(): ?string
    {
        return $this->libelle;
    }

    public function setLibelle(?string $libelle): self
    {
        $this->libelle = $libelle;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDate(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->date;
    }

    public function setDate(?\DateTimeInterface $date): self
    {
        $this->date = $date;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getMontant(): ?string
    {
        return $this->montant;
    }

    public function setMontant(?string $montant): self
    {
        $this->montant = $montant;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getIdfichefrais(): ?Fichefrais
    {
        return $this->idfichefrais;
    }

    public function setIdfichefrais(?Fichefrais $idfichefrais): self
    {
        $this->idfichefrais = $idfichefrais;

        return $this;
    }


}
```